# tree view using Nested tables alignment issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to show hierarchical tree-view in tables. I am trying to create a table inside a parent table when expand is clicked. The child table columns are not aligning properly, even though I gave the same td width using css..

In the below image(http://i60.tinypic.com/352qm2u.jpg) red color lines shows the column reference, where child tds content has to come.. but content is coming in distracted way..

HTML used

```
<tr class="shaded">
<td>
    <span><input type="checkbox" /></span>
</td>
<td>
    <span ><img src="></span>
</td>
<td>Q1</td><td>785-061 - SHEATH1</td><td>PUMAfinal221 products</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td></td>
  <td colspan="999">
    <div style="height: 180px;overflow-y: auto;">
       <table id="tblProducts185346" >
           <tbody >
             <tr >
               <td><input type="checkbox" ></td>
              <td>Q1</td><td>785-061 - SHEATH1</td><td>PUMAfinal221                         products</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
       </table>
    </div>
</td>
</tr>
 ...... ``
```

Any idea on how to fix this issue?

Comment: What image? Make a JSFiddle so it's easier to understand and help resolve your issue.

Comment: As i dont have enough reputation i couldnt post images.. I hosted the image in tinypic website.. please click link below.. http://i60.tinypic.com/352qm2u.jpg

Comment: Make a JSFiddle demonstrating the problem you're stuck on with relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a javascript method to set the target table tds width based on source table td's..

Thanks BigRabbit for your response..

```js
function FormatTable(src, target) {
  var count=0;
  $(src + ' tr:nth-child(2)').eq(0).children("td").each(function() {
      $(target + ' tr:first-child').eq(0).children("td")[count].width = $(this).css("width"); //this.offsetWidth+'px';
      count = count + 1;
    }
  });
}
```